# hadoop fs commands not giving any output

Tags: hadoop

I am running hadoop 1.2.1 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS in pseudo distributed mode, and the fs commands are not doing anything, i.e. niether prompt is returned nor any error message. what is the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
```

I guess you have installed hadoop using the sandbox.